# Slim Framework sub routing

Tags: php, routes, slim, slim-3

I want to use sub routes with Slim Framework v3.2.0 like so:

- www.test.com/ **<-- index page**
- www.test.com/foodtype/ **<-- separate page**
- www.test.com/foodtype/page/ **<-- subcategory of foodtype**

As I understand it, only one get can be called. Currently I have this in my routes.php:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
// Load index page
});

$app->get('/{foodtype}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
// Load page based on the value of $args['foodtype'] 
});
```

***How can I add the separate optional route for page1?***

I've tried:

```
$app->get('/{foodtype}/{page}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
// Load page based on the value of $args['foodtype'] and $args['page']
});
```

This causes a 'page not found' error. I presume I need to escape the optional '/' too?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make the page part optional in your original route.

As in:

```
$app->get('/{foodtype}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
// Load page based on the value of $args['foodtype'] 
});
```

becomes:

```
$app->get('/{foodtype}[/{page}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
// Load page based on the value of $args['foodtype'] and $args['page']
});
```